# How to shorten the boolean function

Tags: boolean-operations

I have the following function:

```
f(x) = (x2 + x1x3x5)(x4 + x3x5x6)(x5 + x6)
```

How can I make the expression like:

```
f(x) = x1x2x3 + x2x3x4 + ...
```

out of this? Is there any method?

I'm not sure if SO is the right place to post this...I guess it's not, but still, I found the tag and around 100 posts with it, so here I am :P

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the boolean algebra you can just multiply them as ordinary numbers.
So (x2 + x1x3x5)(x5 + x6) will be x2x5 + x2x6 + x1x3x5x5 + x1x3x5x6. But again as far as I remember this applied only to "AND" not to "OR"

Answer (score 0):

Well this looks more like a math question.

But if I understand what you want correctly it would look like this

```
x2x4x5+x2x4x6+x2x3x5x6x5+x2x3x5x6x6+x1x3x5x4 ext.
```

basically 
(a1+a2)a3=a1a3+a2a3 
(a1+a2)(a3+a4)=a1a3+a1a4+a2a3+a3a4

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
(x2x4x5 + x1x3x5)(x4x6) + (x2x5 + x1x3x5)(x3x5x6)
(x2x4x5x6 + x1x3x4x5x6) + (x2x5 + x1x3x5)(x3x5x6)
x2x4x5x6 + x1x3x4x5x6 + x2x3x5x6 + x1x3x5x6
x2x4x5x6 + x1x3(x4x5x6 + x5x6) + x2x3x5x6
x2x5x6(x4+1) + x1x3(x4x5x6 + x5x6)
x2x4x5x6 + x1x3(x5x6(x4+1))
x2x4x5x6 + x1x3(x4x5x6)
x2x4x5x6 + x1x3x4x5x6
(x2+x1x3)x4x5x6
```

I probably made a mistake somewhere, so you should test it first.

Answer (score 0):

Your original:

```
f(x) = (x2 + x1x3x5)(x4 + x3x5x6)(x5 + x6)
```

Now using some simple maths:

```
f(x) = (x2x4 + x2x3x5x6 + x1x3x5x4 + x1x3x5x3x5x6)(x5 + x6)

f(x) = x2x4x5 + x2x3x5x6x5 + x1x3x5x4x5 + x1x3x5x3x5x6x5 + x2x4x6 + x2x3x5x6x6 + x1x3x5x4x6 + x1x3x5x3x5x6x6
```

Simplifying gets us the answer (though not necessarily shorter),

```
f(x) = x2x4x5 + x2x3x5x6 + x1x3x5x4x5 + x1x3x5x6 + x2x4x6 + x2x3x5x6 + x1x3x5x4x6 + x1x3x5x6
```